# Find all numbers $x$ for which $(x-\pi)(x+5)(x-3)>0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Hi I'm working my way through Spivak calculus third edition.

Question

> Find all numbers $x$ for which
>   $$(x-\pi)(x+5)(x-3)>0$$

My own path
$$(x-\pi)(x-3)>0 \text{ and } x+5>0 $$
From this I believe that $x>-5$
And since, $x-\pi>0$ then $x>\pi$

The answer says that $x>\pi$ or $-5$  and $x<3$
But I don't understand how can $x$ be bigger than $\pi$, but smaller than $3$?

Comment: Draw a picture, write a table.

Comment: @Djhoe: You're misrepresenting the book's answer. It should be
$$-5 < x < 3\;\;\text{or}\;\;x >\pi$$

Comment: Since the function is continuous, it can only change sign at places where the function is zero. Based on that, follow the strategy outlined in Jack's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{array}{|c|ccccccc||}x&-\infty&&-5&&3&&\pi&&+\infty \\x-\pi&-\infty &&-&&&&0&+&+\infty \\x-3&-\infty&&-&&0&&+&&+\infty\\x+5&-\infty&-&0&&&+&&&+\infty\\f&-\infty&-&|&+&|&-&|&+&+\infty\end{array}

So $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in(-5,3)\cup(\pi,+\infty)$

Comment: Thanks, I also realized graphing the function as a cubic polynomial would show a similar answer!

Answer (score 2):

Note that $-5<3<\pi$ divide the real line into four disjoint open intervals, on each of which you can decide the sign of the function on the left hand side of the inequality easily.

Comment: Excuse me, would you be able to paint it in here?

Comment: You don't need the picture; all you need is to look at the sign on each interval.